# javascript function does not execute in html

Tags: javascript, html

This has to be a simple question but I can't find the answer.  I am trying to call my javascript function "Update_PointTracker_Account" within a modal so it executes when the modal is opened.  For some reason it won't execute.  However, the Onclick button calls the function perfectly.  What am I doing wrong?

```
            <div class="modal hide fade" id="Refresh_PointTracker_Program" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header" align='center'>
                <h3>Refreshing PointTracker Program</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center">
                <p> The points program is being refreshed</p>
            </div>

            <div style="text-align: center" id='updated_program_list'></div>

            <script>
                Update_PointTracker_Account();
            </script>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button onclick ="Update_PointTracker_Account()" class="btn"  aria-hidden="true">Update</button>
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where is that function at? Sounds like you are trying to execute it before it exists.

Comment: The function 'Update_PointTracker_Account()' is located in my 'pointtracker.js" file.  That file is included at the top of my html.  So, isn't the function already defined?  My onclick='Update_PointTracker_Account" works fine in the bottom of the modal. Why? thx

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have not defined the function `Update_PointTracker_Account()` at all.

It has to appear somewhere in the page, either as an inline JS or an imported JS file, and should look like:

```
function Update_PointTracker_Account() {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I did import my pointtracker.js file (which contains my function) at the beginning of my html.  The Onclick works fine though for calling the function.

Comment: @Terry how do you reckon it doesn't exist at all, considering it runs on button click?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this modal is being loaded with `.innerHTML` somewhere.

`<script>` tags do not run when inserted with `innerHTML`. Instead, you should call the function when you assign the `innerHTML`. The reason the button click works is because it's handled differently.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a callback when you call your modal or verify if `Update_PointTracker_Account()` is declared before the call.

Answer (score 0):

first: unless You are in a html5 doc You should add type attribute to script tag, second: the function exists? hope it helps

Comment: The function is defined in my pointtracker.js files that is included before (at top) of the html.

Comment: ok... and the modal is loaded via ajax or is simply hidden and shown at right time?

Comment: The modal is hidden and shown with an on click.  I also tried to put the actual function in the modal to rule out an undefined reference issue. I get the same problem. The script does not run.